# Converting 1-D String array to 2-D char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm working on a program that requires me to take in a 1-D String array from a file and turn it into a 2-D array. Taking in the array from the file works fine, but I can't get the second part to work.

The code I'm working with is:

```
char[][] array2 = new char [7][5];

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    array2[i]= array[i].toCharArray();   
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
         System.out.println(array2[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The array is supposed to print in a grid format, but is printing downward.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How can a 1d string be converted to a 2d char array?

Comment: println prints a line break at the end of the line. use print to print without line break

Comment: To add on to @njzk2's comment, use `print` inside the `j` loop to print each character in a string in one row, and then immediately following that loop block, use `println();` to go to a new line for the next string/char array.

Comment: It is printing the right way now, but it is only printing out the first row, after that it prints out blank for the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print` instead of `println` in inner loop and after each loop print a blank line with `println`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // see changes 5/7. You did "new char[7][5]" not [5][7]
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) // see changes 7/5
    {
         System.out.print(array2[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Update:**

Following is a program that convert String array to 2D char array.

```
public class StringToChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArr = { "HELLO", "WORLD" };
        char[][] char2D = new char[strArr.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            char2D[i] = strArr[i].toCharArray();
        }

        for (char[] char1D : char2D) {
            for (char c : char1D)
                System.out.print(c + " ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you wouldnt happen to know why im getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException" after the first line is printed?

Comment: Thanks again, the exception is gone. Now i just need to figure out why the array only prints out one line and ignores the rest.

Comment: @user2817804 :). Actually, your question is quite incomplete. However, if you feel like you've got your answer, you can close this question.

Comment: Well since you asked lol, any idea why the array is only printing out the first line? Could there be a an issue coming from changing the 1d string to the 2d char?

Comment: @user2817804 I've written program for that. Check it out: https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/6715379#file-stringtochar-java

Answer (score 1):

few suggestions,

1. replace `char[][] array2 = new char [7][5];` with `char[][] array2 = new char [array1.length][];` (where `array1` holds your strings), so your 2d array will have as many rows as you have strings
2. your loop

> > ```
> > for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
> > {
> >     for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
> > ....
> >  }
> > ```

change to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
{ 
   for (int j = 0; j <  array2[i].length; j++)
....
```

another thing is if you want your string printed in rows, use `System.out.print`, and whenever you finished inner loop, print out`'\n'` character

Answer (score 0):

You are using `println`, which is why each character is printed on its own line. You must use `print` instead.

Note that your initialization with

```
new char [7][5];
```

doesn't work as you expect because the inner arrays will be overwritten. Use

```
new char[7][]
```

for the same result, but more clarity as to your intent. Here

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
```

you have apparently reversed the order of indices: you are iterating only through 5 outer arrays, but you have allocated 7. What you should do instead is check against the actual array length and not a hardcoded number. The inner array may be of any size, after all (it depends on the string length).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

If it is printing downwards then change

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)  //row loop
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) //column loop
     {
        System.out.print(array2[i][j]);
     }
    System.out.println(); //add here 
  }
```

Have a look at

1. [formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)
2. [print vs println](http://java-intellectual.blogspot.in/2011/10/what-is-difference-between-print-and.html)

Comment: array1 is probably an array of String, here

Comment: @njzk2: ohh! I missed that. Thanks Sir.